# JavaScript function doesn't execute everything

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have an array `Orte` that contains postcode and the name of the city.
Now I want to change the dropdown depending on the number entered in the input field.
The input field has an `onchange` function. The function is the one below.

The script works so far except the last line after the for loop. It never adds the last part and I don't know why.
Can someone help me please.

Thanks in advance for the anwsers!
Burzi

```
function updateOrt(eingabe){    
    document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML = '<select name="ort">'
    for (var i = 1; i <= Orte.length; i++){ 
        if(Orte[i].PLZ == eingabe){
            document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML += '<option value="' + Orte[i].id + '">' + Orte[i].Ort + '</option>'
        }
    } 
    document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML += "</select>"
}
```

Comment: What is the "last part"?

Comment: use var myOrt = document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter"); don't retrieve it again every time .

Comment: Arrays are zero-based. `i=0; i<Orte.length`

Comment: Using `.innerHTML += htmlPart;` will most likely never have the expected result. Whenever you change `innerHTML` it will immediately parsed into DOM, as of that an incomplete html code will be fixed. `innerHTML += "</select>"` will never have an effect, as `.innerHTML` cannot be incomplete.

Comment: I'm also german, but please don't write names/functions/vars in german. It's a nightmare for every non-german developer you want to work with or who needs to work with your code. Write international code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the innerHTML in one shot. Build up the string first, then assign it. Also, arrays are zero-indexed, so I am guessing you want to start at 0, and end once it is the length of `Orte` (i = Orte.length).

```
function updateOrt(eingabe){
    var str = '<select name="ort">'
    for (var i = 0; i < Orte.length; i++){ 
        if(Orte[i].PLZ == eingabe){
            str += '<option value="' + Orte[i].id + '">' + Orte[i].Ort + '</option>'
        }
    } 
    str += "</select>"
    // now assign the str to innerHTML
    document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the array loop.

You are going from 1 to Orte.length, when it reaches Orte.length it throws an exception and the code after the loop does not execute.

you should do it this way:

```js
function updateOrt(eingabe){    
    document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML = '<select name="ort">'
    for (var i = 0; i < Orte.length; i++){ 
        if(Orte[i].PLZ == eingabe){
            document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML += '<option value="' + Orte[i].id + '">' + Orte[i].Ort + '</option>'
        }
    } 
    document.getElementById("ort_platzhalter").innerHTML += "</select>"
}
```

because arrays in javascript are 0 indexed and go up to length-1